# Standard normal distribution transformation, result pdf or cdf?

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$
We put $Y = \frac{X^2}{2}$
. I want to determine the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ and its probability density.

This is what I did:

$F_Y (y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(\frac{X^2}{2} \leq y) = P( -\sqrt{2y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{2y} = \int_{-\sqrt{2y}}^{\sqrt{2y}} f_X(y) dy $ $= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{2y}}^{\sqrt{2y}} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} = -\frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt{y\pi}}$

The teacher said this is the $PDF$ and not the $CDF$, but I am sure he was not paying attention or something like that, because my approach is standard and correct I think, or what is wrong with it?

Comment: The last equality is wrong.

Comment: I modified it, sorry

Comment: Your second last expression is the CDF, by differentiating it you get the PDF.

Comment: The modified answer is also wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm does it lack some sign or it is in principal wrong?

Comment: You are subconsciously differentiating then integral and calling it the value of the integral.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, I verified again, I missed  a sign, and I didn't differentiate, I integrated

Comment: @user1125632 In case of the normal distribution the pdf cannot be integrated. To express the cdf you write $\Phi(y)$ to express $P(Y\leq y)$.So the cdf is $ \Phi(\sqrt{2y}) -\Phi(-\sqrt{2y}) $

Comment: @callculus42 Why? The above is not correct? I believe it is possible, can you please explain why? we know that $e^f$ has this primitive $\frac{e^f}{f'}$

Comment: By the way, that s the standard normal distribution

Comment: @user1125632 You can read everywhere on the net, that the pdf of the normal distribution cannot be integrated, see also the [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29+dx).

Comment: If you considered $Z=X^2$ and $Y=\frac12Z$ then $Z \sim \chi^2_1$, which has a simple pdf but no closed form cdf, and so the same is true for $Y$